# In magento 1.9.2.4 , values of attributes in are not showing in layered navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In magento 1.9.2.4 , values of attributes in are not showing in layered navigation[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem with version patch. so we have upload the patch_v1.9.1.x app and skin.